# Swap between probability measure and expectation value

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I am reading the book [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](https://books.google.de/books?id=Y5bxBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I am trying to understand the following transformation on page 13:

[image: from probabilty measure to expectation value]

where $T,B$ and $E$ are i.i.d. random variables with probabiltiy density $e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$, i.e

$$ P[T \leq x] = P[E \leq x] = P[B \leq x] = \int_0^x e^{-u} \, du $$

First of all, I wonder of the stated equation is actually true, because I have the feeling it should be

$$ \begin{align*} & \quad P\{T+B < 7 - log 2, T+B+E \geq 7 \} \\ 
                 & \quad + P\{T+B \geq 7-log2, T+B+E < 7 \} \\
                 &= E\{\color{red}{(1-e^{-(7-T-B)})}I_{\{T+B<T-log 2\}}\} \\
                 & \quad+ \color{red}{E}\{\color{red}{e^{-(7-T-B)}}I_{\{7>T+B \geq 7-log 2\}}\}
 \end{align*}$$

I would like to know how he made the transformation. Is it maybe in general  true that if $P[X \leq x] = \int_0^x \mu(x) \, dx$ holds, that one can say
$$ P[X \leq f(Z)] = E[\mu(f(Z))]?$$

Comment: Several facts you may want to know: By the definition of indicator/Bernoulli random variable, $E[I_A] = 1 \times P(A) + 0 \times P(A^c) = P(A)$; $P(A \cap B) = E[I_{A \cap B}] = E[I_AI_B]$. Finally in your question, you can apply the double expectation similar to this: $\Pr\{X \leq u, X + Y \leq v\} = E[I_{X \leq u}I_{X + Y \leq v}] = E[E[I_{X \leq u}I_{X + Y \leq v}|X]] = E[I_{X \leq u}E[I_{X + Y \leq v}|X]]$

Comment: @BGM THANK YOU!! That was exactly what I was looking for!